# Same Page validation next to field

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, field

I am trying to get my error code one the same page just below the field, What I am currently getting is a separate page opening with saying: 'You did not fill out the required fields'

Here is my HTML code for the form:

```
<!-- Header Code -->

<style type="text/css">
.OBJ-1 { margin:0;background:transparent url('wpimages/wp2ce4b072.png') no-repeat left top; }
.P-1 { text-align:center;line-height:1px;font-family:"Tahoma", sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-variant:normal;font-size:18.0px;vertical-align:0; }
.C-1 { line-height:22.00px;font-family:"Tahoma", sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:none;font-variant:normal;font-size:18.0px;vertical-align:0; }
.C-2 { line-height:18.00px;font-family:"Georgia", serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#626262;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:none;font-variant:normal;font-size:16.0px;vertical-align:0; }
.OBJ-2 { border:none;border-radius:10px / 10px;background:#ffffff;font-family:Georgia;text-align:left;font-size:18px;color:#000000; }
.OBJ-3 { border:none;border-radius:10px / 10px;background:#626262;font-family:Georgia;text-align:center;font-size:18px;color:#fdfdfd; }
```

```
<!-- Form form_14 -->


<form id="form_14"  action="dbtest2.php" method="post" target="_top" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="OBJ-1"  style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:42px;width:335px;height:104px;">

<div  style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:4px;width:327px;height:22px;overflow:hidden;">
    <p class="Body P-1"><span class="C-1">sign up</span></p>
</div>

<label for="">

    <div  style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:30px;width:327px;height:18px;overflow:hidden;">
        <p class="Body"><span class="C-2"><br></span></p>
    </div>

</label>


<!-- Form Edit Box -->


<input name="firstname" class="OBJ-2" maxlength="32" placeholder="firstname" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:48px;width:327px;height:24px;">



<!-- Form Button -->


<input name="submit" class="OBJ-3" type="submit" value="submit"  style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:76px;width:327px;height:24px;">
```

This is my PHP field validation script:

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
if(empty($firstname))
{
echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}



$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="correoervhanski"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or
die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");



?>
```

If someone could kindly tell me how to place the code for the validation message to appear just below the field will be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm pretty much new to AJAX and PHP to some degree. Is there anyway I could use PHP to implement the php to run on the same page?  And where in the code above will I need to insert the script? Sorry i must sound like a daft bugger. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

Basically, you are trying to run PHP scripts on the same page - for this, your best tactic is using AJAX. This is very easy to implement, particularly if you're using the jquery library;

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/